# C++ I have two questions

Tags: c++, arrays, programming-languages

Please help me with my homework:

- There is an array a [20] of float numbers, Enter number
  in the array. Find the sum of negative number.
- Enter 10 integer numbers in the array a [10]. Find the
  sum of positive numbers.

Comment: This is homework I guess? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes this is for homework Can you help me. please!

Comment: Try something, and if it doesn't work, come back here with what you've tried. Then we'll help you. Because it currently looks like you're asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: We're not against giving you advice, but please give us more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? We're not just going to give you the answer.

Comment: You should discuss such questions with your classmates, so that everyone of you benefit from each other. Solve such problems together if can't solve alone.

Comment: If you seriously have no idea where to start at all, I would take it up with your teacher. There must be a book you're using? Course notes? That should get you started with at least the very basics. Otherwise I would look at some of the various threads on this site, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159/what-is-the-best-source-to-learn-c

Comment: @SinaN, do you understand the problem? If not, how do you expect to understand any solution we provide (if anyone was inclined to provide you one anyway!)? Don't be lazy, don't just ask for teh codez, use the grey mushy thing between your ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General psuedo-code to get you in the right direction for finding the sum of positive numbers in the array:

```
float result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
{
  if(array[i] > 0)
    result = result + array[i];
}
```

For the sum of negative numbers, just switch the if-statement. Of course, this isn't exactly C++ code, but I think you can make it work from here pretty easily enough. :)

Comment: Well I guess it could be. Honestly, I've never written a line of C++, so I don't exactly know. I just put that down as general code.

Answer (score 0):

You access a value with the `[]` operator, so for instance, accessing the first value from the array `a`, you write `a[0]`.

After that it is a matter of using `for` to iterate over the numbers.